# Play: How to implement action composition

Tags: scala, playframework

Given the followoing `ActionBuilder` implementations:

```
class SignedRequest[A](request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request) {}

object SignedAction extends ActionBuilder[SignedRequest] {

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: SignedRequest[A] => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
    block(new SignedRequest(request))
  }   
}     

class SecuredRequest[A](request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request) {}

object SecuredRequest extends ActionBuilder[SecuredRequest] {

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: SecuredRequest[A] => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
    block(new SecuredRequest(request))
  }   
}
```

How do I combine them? I've tried the following...

```
object MyController extends Controller {

  def doSomething = SignedAction.async(parse.json) {
    SecuredAction.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
      Future.successful(Ok)
  }}
}
```

... but I always get the following error message:

```
/home/j3d/test/controllers/MyController.scala:37: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult]
[error]       SecuredAction.async(parse.json) {
                                              ^
```

Am I missing something? Tx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function `async` is expecting a `Future[SimpleResult]`, but the nested `SecuredAction.async` is returning an `Action` to the top `SignedAction.async` (notes that in your sample code you omit to declare requests as `class` and `SignedAction` is declared twice).

You can compose result of nested `SecuredAction` within `SignedAction` by applying it to the signed request.

```
package controllers

import scala.concurrent.Future

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

case class SignedRequest[A](request: Request[A]) 
    extends WrappedRequest[A](request) {}

object SignedAction extends ActionBuilder[SignedRequest] {

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], 
    block: SignedRequest[A] => Future[Result]) = 
    block(new SignedRequest(request))

}     

case class SecuredRequest[A](request: Request[A]) 
    extends WrappedRequest[A](request) {}

object SecuredAction extends ActionBuilder[SecuredRequest] {

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], 
    block: SecuredRequest[A] => Future[Result]) = 
    block(new SecuredRequest(request))

}

object MyController extends Controller {
  def doSomething = SignedAction.async(parse.json) { signedReq =>
    SecuredAction.async(parse.json) { implicit securedReq =>
      Future.successful(Ok)
    } apply signedReq
  }
}
```

Such action composition can also be done without `ActionBuilder` (which can lead to some extra complexity).

```
package controllers

import scala.concurrent.Future

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

case class SignedRequest[A](request: Request[A])
case class SecuredRequest[A](request: Request[A]) 

object MyController extends Controller {
  def Signed[A](bodyParser: BodyParser[A])(signedBlock: SignedRequest[A] => Future[Result]): Action[A] = Action.async(bodyParser) { req => 
    signedBlock(SignedRequest(req)) 
  }

  def Secured[A](bodyParser: BodyParser[A])(securedBlock: SecuredRequest[A] => Future[Result]): Action[A] = Action.async(bodyParser) { req => 
    securedBlock(SecuredRequest(req)) 
  }

  def doSomething = Signed(parse.json) { signedReq =>
    Secured(parse.json) { implicit securedReq =>
      Future.successful(Ok)
    } apply signedReq.request
  }
}
```

Composition can be also done around `Future[Result]`:

```
package controllers

import scala.concurrent.Future

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue

case class SignedRequest[A](request: Request[A])
case class SecuredRequest[A](request: Request[A]) 

object MyController extends Controller {
  def Signed[A](signedBlock: SignedRequest[A] => Future[Result])(implicit req: Request[A]): Future[Result] = signedBlock(SignedRequest(req))

  def Secured[A](signedBlock: SecuredRequest[A] => Future[Result])(implicit req: Request[A]): Future[Result] = signedBlock(SecuredRequest(req))

  def doSomething = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit req =>
    Signed[JsValue] { signedReq =>
      Secured[JsValue] { securedReq => Future.successful(Ok) } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've just tried your solution and it works, but it seems the JSON body  is parsed twice (one per ActionBuilder). Is there a way to optimize this? Thank you very much.

Comment: The parsing issue is why I'm not sure `ActionBuilder` is the easiest way to go to have an obvious solution. Would you mind accepting the answer as your initial question (compilation error) is solved?

Comment: @j3d Just added another composition example which only use plain function (no `ActionBuilder` inheritance) and works with `Future[Result]` without parsing JSON many times.

Answer (score 1):

Using [action-zipper](https://github.com/t2v/action-zipper) you can compose `ActionBuilders`

```
import jp.t2v.lab.play2.actzip._

object MyController extends Controller {

  val MyAction = SignedAction zip SecuredAction 

  def doSomething = MyAction.async(parse.json) { case (signedReq, secureReqeq) =>
    Future.successful(Ok)
  }
}
```

Json parsing will be executed only once :)

Answer (score -2):

to simplify @applicius answer
I think it can be done without the Future, I think async/Future is a separate concern.

Very simply removing Futures and async, we get this:

```
    def signed[A](signedBlock: SignedRequest[A] => Result)(implicit req: Request[A]) = signedBlock(SignedRequest(req))
    def secured[A](securedBlock: SecuredRequest[A] => Result)(implicit req: Request[A]) = securedBlock(SecuredRequest(req))

    //the use is the same as with Futures except for no async

    def doSomething = Action(parse.json) { implicit req =>
         signed[JsValue] { signedReq => secured[JsValue] { securedReq =>
         Ok  
    } } }
```

Comment: Action composition and async are separate, but question there involves both