# How to increase flexibility in scala play frameworkd

Tags: playframework

I posted this on play framework google group but they deleted it for some reason. Maybe with good reason though im finding it hard to go from a dynamic web framework to static one like Play.

The problem is im used to being able to set random variables in the controller and have them be detected in a display element somewhere in the views and deal with it. In play you have to defined everything up front that you will pass in to your view elements and then from that view you then need to keep passing the elements to the next view element until eventually it gets to where it needs to be.

I realise you can do composite objects that wrap WrappedReqest e.g.

```
case class UserDataRequest[A](val user: User, val cart: Cart,
request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest(request)
```

and pass objects of type UserDataRequest but this still isnt that flexible.

you could pass a map of type [String,Any] but this feels like a cheat possibly and you will have to cast key values to the appropriate type, which isnt too bad.

Does anyone who uses play have any advice on how to overcome this? Does anyone do the last case?

In my company we have to be very flexible and be able to add ad hoc hacks for sponsored content etc that is very hard to capture up front so sometimes we have to trigger a page element based on an id of a single item. I wouldnt want to refactor each time to do this.

I guess you could employ a hybrid of the above e.g.

```
case class MyRequest[A](val user: User, val item: Item, data: Map[String,Any]
request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest(request)
```

but you still need to pass the data object all the way down from one function call to the next till it reaches its target. In the above i would want the data map to be magically available in templates.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have a clear view of the documentation and how it work. Indeed Play is statically typed, which doesn't mean it's static for all, but that it tries to be the more typesafe it can on the Web (which is a great advantage).

You should read:

1. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActions
2. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms
3. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaSessionFlash
4. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActionsComposition (e.g. [Play: How to implement action composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105558/play-how-to-implement-action-composition/25106115#25106115) )

Comment: I have read them and the play for scala book. All i see is examples where you have a single or maybe a couple of objects that you pass to a view that are used in that view, but im interested in cases where you might need a object or set a flag that are not needed in that first view or maybe even a child of that view but maybe a child of a child. How do i pass that flag, object etc to those sub views without the tedium of argument passing and changing intermediate views. Which of the above links solves this issue? I dont think implicit args solves it either.

Comment: If you have read docs, you should have see Play templates: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaTemplates

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of this there is no way to do this, you have to pass everything to the principal view in the controller from what i can see. Implicits wont work for this from what i understand of them either for my scenario. 
If anyone can be bothered saying otherwise please correct me as i would love to know a better way.
So much for decoupling.