# Decorating a Scala Play Controller with Java class Secured extends Security.Authenticator

Tags: scala, authentication, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm refactoring a Play 2.3 app in Java to Scala. Existing Java controllers are decorated like so for authentication.

`@Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
public class Application extends Controller { ... }`

The signature of Secured.java is:

`public class Secured extends Security.Authenticator { ... }`

How might I decorate my Scala controller with the same Secured.java?

I've tried not doing that by writing a second Secured2.scala as a trait and doing authentication the Scala way in Play but many of the existing templates rely on Secured.java to get the current user so that's why I'm trying to make my Scala controller compatible with the Java Secured class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play: How to implement action composition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105558/play-how-to-implement-action-composition)

Comment: Even though the outcome might be the same, my question is different because I am asking how to use a Java annotation in Scala controllers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'd be able to use the same Java class for authentication using the scala API of play. But here's how you'd do it using the scala API and you can fill in the gaps with your Secured class code:

```
trait Authentication {
  // Define what you want your auth header to be
  val AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER = "X-AUTH-TOKEN"

  object Authenticated extends Security.AuthenticatedBuilder(checkHeader(_), onUnauthorized(_))

  def checkHeader(request: RequestHeader): Option[String] = {
    request.headers.get(AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER) flatMap { token =>
      // do a check to see if there is a user and get their name
    }
  }

  def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = {
    // Do something when the user isn't authorized to access a route
    Results.Unauthorized
  }
}

trait SecuredController extends Controller with Authentication
```

And here is how it would look in an actual controller:

```
object SomeController extends SecuredController {
  def someApi = Authenticated { req =>
    // do something
    // The username is available in the request
    val username: String = req.user
    Ok
  }
}
```