# Custom Action composition to authorize based on JSON token in Play (Scala)

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Unlike most discussions on Action composition (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105558/play-how-to-implement-action-composition)), I need to parse the incoming JSON request in my Action. This is because our application delivers a security token embedded in the JSON (not in the header, as is typical).

What I'd like to achieve is this:

```
object AuthenticatedAction extends ActionBuilder[UserRequest] with ActionTransformer[Request, UserRequest] {
    // Do something magical here that will:
    // 1. parse the inbound request.body.validate[GPToken]
    // 2. (do stuff with the token to check authorization)
    // 3. if NOT authorized return an HTTP NOTAUTHORIZED or FORBIDDEN
    // 4. otherwise, forward the request to the desired endpoint
}

object SomeController extends Controller
    val action = AuthenticatedAction(parse.json) { implicit request =>
        request.body.validate[SomeRequest] match {
            // Do whatever... totally transparent and already authorized
        }
    }
    ...
```

The inbound JSON will always have a token, e.g.:

```
{
    "token":"af75e4ad7564cfde",
    // other parameters we don't care about
}
```

So, I'm thinking to parse just want we want (and **not** end up parsing complex, deeply nested JSON structures) I could just have a GPToken object:

```
class GPToken(token: String)
object GPToken { implicit val readsToken = Json.reads[GPToken] }
```

Then in the "magic" of AuthenticationAction I could deserialize just the token, do my thing with the database to check authorization, and either pass the request on or send back a NOTAUTHORIZED. But this is where I'm getting lost... how do I get the json body, parse it, and filter all incoming requests through my security layer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play: How to implement action composition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105558/play-how-to-implement-action-composition)

Comment: Note a dupe, but very, very close. In this case we need to interpret the inbound JSON (not the request header) and I'm having trouble doing that. The referenced article talks about using the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to move that token to your request headers. Doing so will allow you to use Play's AuthententicatedBuilder which is an ActionBuilder to help with authentication.

If you can do this then you could have a trait like so:

```
trait Authentication {
  object Authenticated extends play.api.mvc.Security.AuthenticatedBuilder(checkGPToken(_), onUnauthorized(_))

  def checkGPToken(request: RequestHeader): Option[User] = {
    request.headers.get("GPToken") flatMap { token =>
      // Do the check with the token
      // Return something about the user that will be available inside your actions
    }
  }

  def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = {
    // Do something when it doesn't pass authorization
    Results.Unauthorized
  }
}
```

Now with your controllers, you can create an action that requires authentication quite simply.

```
object SomeController extends Controller with Authentication {
    def someAction = Authenticated { req =>
      // Your user your header check is available
      val user = req.user
      // Do something in the context of being authenticated
      Ok
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, this makes more sense. Unfortunately, our existing application embeds the security token into all JSON requests (as the first element, named "token"). I know it's odd, but that's the way it is...