# Play 2.4 ActionBuilder / ActionFunction, BodyParsers and JSON

Tags: json, scala, parsing, playframework, playframework-2.4

In a Play 2.4 project, I created an Action that do three things.

1. check that a specific header is present. If not, returns a HTTP error.
2. use the header value to authenticate the user (a authentication function will be passed to that Action). If the auth fails returns an HTTP error
3. parse the JSON body to a case class and give it to the Action block code.

To do that, I used the Play Action composition mecanism explain in this page : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaActionsComposition
but more specifically, the final result I wanted is explained here :
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaActionsComposition#Putting-it-all-together

I succeeded to write this:

```scala
package actions

import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import play.api.mvc.{WrappedRequest, _}

import scala.concurrent.Future

object Actions {

  case class WithApiKeyRequest[A](apiKey: String, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)
  case class ParsedJsonRequest[A](parsed: Any, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

  def AuthenticatedAndParsed[T, A](authencation: String => Future[_])(implicit reader: Reads[T]): ActionBuilder[ParsedJsonRequest] =
    WithApiKeyHeaderAction andThen AuthentificationAction(authencation) andThen JsonAction

  private[this] def WithApiKeyHeaderAction = new ActionBuilder[WithApiKeyRequest] {
    override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (WithApiKeyRequest[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] =
      request.headers.get("ApiKey") match {
        case Some(apiKey: String) => block(WithApiKeyRequest(apiKey, request))
        case _                    => Future.successful { BadRequest(Json.obj("errors" -> "ApiKey header needed")) }
      }
  }

  private[this] def AuthentificationAction(authencationFunction: String => Future[_]) = new ActionFilter[WithApiKeyRequest] {
    override protected def filter[A](request: WithApiKeyRequest[A]): Future[Option[Result]] =
      authencationFunction(request.apiKey)
        .map { _ => None } // Do not filter the request
        .recover { case _ => Some(Unauthorized) }
  }

  private[this] def JsonAction[T](implicit reader: Reads[T]) = new ActionBuilder[ParsedJsonRequest] {
    composeParser(BodyParsers.parse.json)
    override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (ParsedJsonRequest[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
      request.body.asInstanceOf[JsValue].validate[T].fold(
        errors => Future { BadRequest(Json.obj("errors" -> JsError.toJson(errors))) },
        (parsedJson: T) => block(ParsedJsonRequest(parsedJson, request))
      )
    }
  }
}
```

It seems to work well but it's not perfect because I'm force to use the `Any` type in the `case class ParsedJsonRequest[A](parsed: Any, request: Request[A])` because it seems that I can't do that: 
`case class ParsedJsonRequest[T, A](parsed: T, request: Request[A])`

Is it possible to do that ?
Do you think I can improve my solution ? How ?

My question is not about how to do Action composition. I understand how it works and I succeeded to write my ActionBuilders and my wanted composition.
My question is about how to improve my composition.

Thanks
Jules

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play: How to implement action composition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105558/play-how-to-implement-action-composition)

Comment: No because this post only explain a simple case of action composition and do not answer to my questions.

Comment: It's composing actions, using `BodyParser`, so the concepts are the same, the solutions quite similar

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making a new `ActionBuilder` for a JsonRequest, I would simply use the `AuthentificationAction` `ActionBuilder` and pass it a json `BodyParser`:

```
AuthentificationAction(parse.json) { 
  request => // Note that the request has type Request[JsValue]
    doStuffWithJson(request.body)
}
```

Any action using this builder, will get a `Request[JsValue]` rather than a `Request[AnyContent]`.

Comment: I don't find your proposition very useful. The code will be less understandable if I do that