# Equivalent to authenticated routes in akka-http?

Tags: scala, authentication, playframework

This might be a bit of a noob question because I'm only starting out with play. What is the equivalent of authenticated routes which we can find in akka-http? Below is an example of an authenticated route using akka-http

```
def oauth2Authenticator(credentials: Credentials): Future[Option[ScalaFirebaseToken]] = {
    credentials match {
      case p @ Credentials.Provided(token) =>
          ImportFirebaseCredentials.decodeToken(token).flatMap {
            case token : FirebaseToken => {
              Future(Some(
                ScalaFirebaseToken(token.getUid,
                  Option(token.getEmail),
                  Option(token.getName),
                  Option(token.getPicture)
                )))
            }
            case _ => Future.successful(None)
          }
      case _ =>
        println("couldn't obtain credentials")
        Future.successful(None)
    }
  }

  def authenticated = authenticateOAuth2Async("auth", oauth2Authenticator)

  val route =
    path("user") {
      (get & authenticated) { authResult =>
        complete(getUserByUid(authResult.uid, authResult.email, authResult.name))
      }
    }
```

This code obtains the credentials from the requests header, checks it against firebase and then returns the data for this user.

I would love to get an example of how I should authenticate my actions in a similar fashion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play: How to implement action composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105558/play-how-to-implement-action-composition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticated route can be achieved using [action composition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaActionsComposition#Authentication). Here is one example taken from [playframework/play-scala-secure-session-example](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-secure-session-example) which uses `ActionBuilder` to implement authentication via [`UserInfoAction.invokeBlock`](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-secure-session-example/blob/98c1872dd0b6b31126afcb78bca5614a87969add/app/controllers/package.scala#L59):

```
override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (UserRequest[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
  // deal with the options first, then move to the futures
  val maybeFutureResult: Option[Future[Result]] = for {
    sessionId <- request.session.get(SESSION_ID)
    userInfoCookie <- request.cookies.get(USER_INFO_COOKIE_NAME)
  } yield {
    // Future can be flatmapped here and squished with a partial function
    sessionService.lookup(sessionId).flatMap {
      case Some(secretKey) =>
        val cookieBaker = factory.createCookieBaker(secretKey)
        val maybeUserInfo = cookieBaker.decodeFromCookie(Some(userInfoCookie))

        block(new UserRequest[A](request, maybeUserInfo, messagesApi))
      case None =>
        // We've got a user with a client session id, but no server-side state.
        // Let's redirect them back to the home page without any session cookie stuff.
        Future.successful {
          discardingSession {
            Redirect(routes.HomeController.index())
          }.flashing(FLASH_ERROR -> "Your session has expired!")
        }
    }
  }

  maybeFutureResult.getOrElse {
    block(new UserRequest[A](request, None, messagesApi))
  }
}
```

If authentication succeeds the request is enriched with `maybeUserInfo` while if it fails there is a redirect with `Your session has expired` added to flash. Now to add authentication to a route just inject `UserInfoAction` into a controller and [call it](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-secure-session-example/blob/98c1872dd0b6b31126afcb78bca5614a87969add/app/controllers/LoginController.scala#L18) like so:

```
def login = userAction.async { implicit request: UserRequest[AnyContent] =>
  ...
  // request.userInfo is now available
}
```

Comment: `ActionBuilder` is not the only way to compose actions, nor the simplest one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105558/play-how-to-implement-action-composition/25106115#25106115

Answer (score 1):

I cannot speak from experience, but this is the manual page about OAuth in Play! Framework:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaOAuth#OAuth

Also, a list of various modules that provide auth functionality:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ModuleDirectory#Authentication-(Login-&-Registration)-and-Authorization-(Restricted-Access)