# Is it possible to access the request body as a JsValue in action composition functions in Play Framework 2.8?

Tags: scala, playframework

In the Play documentation the Request type is generic [A] for action composition functions.
I am trying to add a custom query object to every endpoint that is responsible for querying data, to do that I need to grab the request body as JsValue and parse it into an appropriate case class. I cant seem to add a type to the WrappedRequest or the refine method in the action, and I cant do `request.body.as[JsValue]` in the refine method. Is there a way accomplish the following?

I would like to do something like this with action composition in endpoints that handle querying  data:

```
def SomeEndpointWithAQuery() = auth.protectedAction(parse.json).andThen(QueryAction)) { request:QueryRequest[JsValue] =>
  val query = request.queryObject
  res = // Do query stuff
  Ok(res)
}
```

QueryRequest is a WrappedRequest that provides a query object:

```
class QueryRequest[A](val query: QueryParser, request: AuthUserRequest[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request) {
  def queryObject = query.parseQuery()
}


object QueryActionObject {
  def QueryAction()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): ActionRefiner[AuthUserRequest, QueryRequest] = new ActionRefiner[AuthUserRequest, QueryRequest] {
    def executionContext: ExecutionContext = ec
    def refine[A](input: AuthUserRequest[A]) = Future.successful {
      val qp = new QueryParser(input.body.as[JsObject])
      if (qp.validate()) {
        Right(new QueryRequest(qp, input))
      } else {
        // bad request handling ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

auth.protectedAction is an actionBuilder that adds user info based on request.session info, it shouldnt affect how this queryAction works.

Comment: Rather than composing the actionbuilders, compose the actions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105558/play-how-to-implement-action-composition/25106115#25106115

Comment: @cchantep, thanks for the reply, however I am not sure how composing actions will work with adding a value to the request. Could you clarify a little there?